# Explain formula using beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, formatting

I am preparing a presentation on statistics. I want to include a slide on Bayes' Theorem which says:

```
p(\theta | D) = \frac{p(D|\theta) p(\theta)} {p(D)}
```

I want to explain each term using arrows. How can I do this?

I tried to follow this [example](https://www.overleaf.com/2978036ftsmgb#/8155135/) but my main problem is that I have a fraction. How can I split the fraction?

[This](http://www.saedsayad.com/images/Bayes_rule.png) is exactly what I want to do. Without the last line.

Comment: Can you prepare a document with just that one slide?

Comment: The linked document has fractions. I assume you want to highlight the terms in the numerator and denominator independently?

Comment: @MikeRenfro, I added an image. It is exactly what I want to do

Comment: You may want to have a look at this example : http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/   Edit, OK, the example you cite is similar.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library; the idea is to place some marks at the desired locations and then to use those marks to have pointers for the explanations:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{Baye's theorem}
\[
\tikzmark{ptd}p(\theta\, |\, D) = \frac{\tikzmark{pdt}p(D\,|\,\theta) p(\theta)}{\tikzmark{pd}p(D)}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  overlay,
  expl/.style={draw=orange,fill=orange!30,rounded corners,text width=3cm},
  arrow/.style={red!80!black,ultra thick,->,>=latex}
]
\node<2->[expl] 
  (ptdex) 
  at (2,-2cm)
  {Some explanation};
\node<3->[expl] 
  (pdtex) 
  at (6,3.5cm)
  {Some other explanation; this one is a little longer};
\node<4->[expl] 
  (pdex) 
  at (9,-3cm)
  {Some other explanation};
\draw<2->[arrow]
  (ptdex) to[out=100,in=180] ([yshift=0.5ex]{pic cs:ptd});  
\draw<3->[arrow]
  (pdtex.west) to[out=180,in=180] ([yshift=0.5ex]{pic cs:pdt});  
\draw<4->[arrow]
  (pdex.north) to[out=90,in=180] ([yshift=0.5ex]{pic cs:pd});  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An animation of the result:

[image]

### Update

If, for some reason, the `tikzmark` library is not available and no overlays are wanted, use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \coordinate (#1);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{Baye's theorem}
\[
\tikzmark{ptd}p(\theta\, |\, D) = \frac{\tikzmark{pdt}p(D\,|\,\theta) p(\theta)\tikzmark{pt}}{\tikzmark{pd}p(D)}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  overlay,
  expl/.style={draw=orange,fill=orange!30,rounded corners,text width=3cm},
  arrow/.style={red!80!black,ultra thick,->,>=latex}
]
\node[expl] 
  (ptdex) 
  at (2,-2cm)
  {Some explanation};
\node[expl] 
  (pdtex) 
  at (4,3.5cm)
  {Some other explanation; this one is a little longer};
\node[expl] 
  (pdex) 
  at (9,-3cm)
  {Some other explanation};
\node[expl] 
  (ptex) 
  at (8,3.5cm)
  {Some other explanation; this one is a little longer};
\draw[arrow]
  (ptdex) to[out=100,in=180] ([yshift=0.5ex]{ptd});  
\draw[arrow]
  (pdtex.west) to[out=180,in=180] ([yshift=0.5ex]{pdt});  
\draw[arrow]
  (pdex.north) to[out=90,in=180] ([yshift=0.5ex]{pd});  
\draw[arrow]
  (ptex.east) to[out=0,in=0] ([yshift=0.5ex]{pt});  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: This is almost what I want. Can it be done using `tikz`? I am having troubles downloading other packages. I am using `ubuntu`. I'd rather do it with `tikz`.

Comment: @po6 `tikzmark` *is* a TikZ library. It comes with modern LaTeX systems. Don't you have it installed? Why is it "almost" what you want? What is missing?

Comment: I still need to define `p(\theta)`. I tried running the code you posted, I got an error: `can't find 'tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex'

Comment: I have though `tikz` installed and it is working fine.

Comment: @po6 Please see my updated answer, The version under "Update" works with just TikZ. Since internal calculations are involved, you need to run the code three times for the arrows to reach their final positions.

Comment: @po6 I guess that taking my code as example, you can do the explanation for the other term.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing. How can I put the explanation all in one slide?

Comment: I tried deleting `<2->, <3->` ... the arrows were deleted

Comment: @po6 Please see my newly updated answer (the code at the bottom). Don't forget that you need three compilations due to  the inner calculations involved.

Comment: One last thing, I tried to add the arrow to the fourth equation, the arrow disappeared. I added the following code: `\node[expl] 
  (pdex) 
  at (9,3.5cm)
  {Prior};`

Comment: @po6 Please, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 11):

Gonzalo's answer is probably better (certainly more flexible), but I'm not going to throw this one away. There's nothing special in having fractions here, it's just a pain to get all the braces and semicolons correctly placed for the `\node` commands. I've also relabeled the nodes to have abbreviated names instead of numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{frame}
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
    \item Class Prior Probability
        \tikz[na]\node [coordinate] (nCPP) {};
    \item Likelihood
        \tikz[na]\node [coordinate] (nL) {};
\end{itemize}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{
\tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (tL) {$p(D|\theta)$};}
\tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=red!20,anchor=base] (tCPP) {$p(\theta)$};}
}
{
\tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=green!20,anchor=base] (tPPP) {$p(D)$};}
}
=
\tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=yellow!20,anchor=base] (tPP) {$p(\theta | D)$};}
\end{equation*}
\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
    \item Predictor Prior Probability
        \tikz[na]\node [coordinate] (nPPP) {};
    \item Posterior probability
        \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (nPP) {};
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[->]<1-> (nCPP) edge [bend left] (tCPP);
        \path[->]<2-> (nL) edge [bend left] (tL);
        \path[->]<3-> (nPPP) edge [out=0, in=0] (tPPP);
        \path[->]<4-> (nPP) edge [out=0, in=-90] (tPP);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using the [`annotate-equations` package](https://github.com/st--/annotate-equations) that I've just put on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/annotate-equations) (building on top of tikzmark and the previous answers here), you can write your example as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{annotate-equations}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\eqnhighlightheight}{\mathstrut}

\begin{equation*}
    \eqnmark{post}{p(\theta | D)} = \frac{\eqnmark{lik}{p(D|\theta)} \eqnmark{prior}{p(\theta)}} {\eqnmark{marglik}{p(D)}}
\end{equation*}
\annotate[yshift=2.5em]{above,right}{lik}{likelihood}
\annotate[yshift=1em]{above,right}{prior}{prior}
\annotate[yshift=1em]{above,left}{post}{posterior}
\annotate[yshift=-1em]{below,right}{marglik}{marginal likelihood}

\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image: rendered output]

The package also supports highlighting and annotating multiple targets with the same text; you can find detailed explanation of the features in the [user manual](https://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/annotate-equations/annotate-equations.pdf) :)

Answer (score 6):

Full credit to Gonzalo's Code. This is just a cleaner (in my opinion) way of obtaining the same effect.

[image: Example image]

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}

%My predefined color
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.15,0.7}

%Set color for Annotations
\colorlet{annotcol}{myblue!80!black}

%Store coordinates of points
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \coordinate (#1);
  }

%Command to add annotation above
\newcommand{\noteup}[3][0em,0em]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  overlay]
\node[draw=annotcol,fill=white,ellipse,very thick,minimum width=2cm] 
  (mynode) 
  at ([shift=($({#1})+({0em,+5.5em})$)]{#2.north})
  {\begin{minipage}{2cm}\centering #3\end{minipage}};
\draw[annotcol,very thick,->,>=latex]
  (mynode.south) to[out=-90,in=+90] ([xshift=0.5em,yshift=1.3em]{#2}); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%Command to add annotation below
\newcommand{\notedown}[3][0em,0em]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  overlay]
\node[draw=annotcol,fill=white,ellipse,very thick,minimum width=2cm] 
  (mynode) 
  at ([shift=($({#1})+({0em,-4em})$)]{#2.south})
  {\begin{minipage}{2cm}\centering #3\end{minipage}};
\draw[annotcol,very thick,->,>=latex]
  (mynode.north) to[out=90,in=-90] ([xshift=0.5em,yshift=-0.1em]{#2}); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}


%Beamer Slides
\begin{document}
\frame{

% Equation
\begin{center}
{\Large $\tikzmark{P}P = \tikzmark{PT}P_T + \tikzmark{PP}P^+ + \tikzmark{PN}P^-$}
\end{center}

%Annotations
\notedown{P}{Total Value of P}
\noteup[-1em,0em]{PT}{Value of P for T}
\noteup[5em,0em]{PP}{Value of P for +}

}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for absolute coordinates and for the instable commands `\tikz[remember picture,overlay]` and `\tikzmark`. We can just let Latex math do the work using `\overset` or `\underset`. The trick is to prohibit `tikz` from creating a big bounding box, which could blow the formula apart.

This solution is not restricted to `beamer`.

Special thanks to Miguel! Your answer really inspired me.

```
\documentclass[16pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{arev}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,shapes}

\newcommand\overnote[3][0em,0em]{% %[relative position] %note above %orig text
    \ensuremath{
        \overset{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \coordinate (refpoint) at (0,0);
                \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
                    \node[draw=red,fill=white,ellipse, very thick,anchor=south] (content) at ($(0,20pt)+({#1})$) {#2};
                    \draw[red, very thick, ->,-triangle 45] (content.south) to[out=-90,in=+90] (0pt,10pt) to (0pt,0pt); 
                \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }{#3}%
    }%
}

\newcommand\undernote[3][0em,0em]{% %[relative position] %note above %orig text
    \ensuremath{
        \underset{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \coordinate (refpoint) at (0,0);
                \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
                    \node[draw=red,fill=white,ellipse, very thick,anchor=north] (content) at ($(0,-20pt)+({#1})$) {#2};
                    \draw[red, very thick, ->,-triangle 45] (content.north) to[out=+90,in=-90] (0pt,-10pt) to (0pt,0pt); 
                \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }{#3}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{center}
            $
                \overnote[-2cm,0cm]{Above a}{a}
                =
                \frac{
                    \sqrt{
                        b
                        +
                        \overnote{Above c}{c}
                    }
                }{
                    \underbrace{
                        \undernote[-2cm,-0.5cm]{Below d}{d}
                        +
                        \undernote[1.5cm,0cm]{Below e}{e}
                    }_{
                        \undernote[-0.5cm,-1cm]{Below f}{f}
                    }
                }
            $
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]