# How can I draw arrows from items to a picture in Beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows

I'm creating a presentation in Beamer, and I have a slide that consists of a few items, and then underneath is a picture. And I want to draw arrows from the items to the picture underneath. How can it be done? Currently, I have just this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I was wondering whether TikZ can help here? But how?

Comment: `remember` option of `tikzpicture`?

Comment: see tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254844 (see @ChristianHupfer 's comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tikzmark` is one option. You can use the information in [the link mentioned in samcarter's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-wit%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bh-tikz/) for help locating the right places to end the arrows.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1\tikzmark{a}
    \item Item 2\tikzmark{b}
    \item Item 3\tikzmark{c}
  \end{itemize}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node {\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-a}};
    \foreach \i/\j in {(0,0)/a,(1,1)/b,(2,2)/c} \draw [red,->] ({pic cs:\j}) -- \i;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: arrows]