# Link formula with TikZ picture in Beamer with two columns

Tags: beamer, overlays, tkz-euclide

I want to link the formula element in TikZ picture... But arrow is not pointing the right place...

Similar to 
[Link formula with TikZ picture in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443529/link-formula-with-tikz-picture-in-beamer)

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} %<-added
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{tcolorbox}%\onslide<3>
                    \begin{align*}
                    \onslide<1->{\sin A &= \frac{\tikznode{Lab1}{\text{Side opposite to }\angle A}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}\\} 
                    \onslide<1->{&= \frac{BC}{AC}\\}
                    \onslide<1->{\sin A &= \frac{7}{25}}
                    \end{align*}
                \end{tcolorbox}
            \end{column}
            %
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
                \begin{tcolorbox}%\onslide<2->
                    \begin{center}  
                        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
                        %\tkzInit[xmax=4, ymax=6]
                        %\tkzAxeXY
                        %\tkzGrid
                        %\tkzClip
                        %
                        \tkzDefPoint(0,4){A}
                        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
                        \tkzDefPoint(2,0){C}

                        \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
                        \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
                        \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)

                        \tkzLabelPoints[below](B,C)
                        \tkzLabelPoints[above](A)

                        \tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.4](A,B,C)

                        \tkzLabelSegment[below,pos=.5,alias=lab1](B,C){7 cm}
                        \tkzLabelSegment[sloped](B,A){24 cm}
                        %\tkzLabelSegment[right,pos=.5,red](B,C){25 cm}
                        \tkzLabelSegment[sloped](C,A){25 cm}
                        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](A,C,B)
                        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.6](B,A,C)
                        %\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5,mark=|](C,B,A)
                        \end{tikzpicture}
                    \end{center}
                \end{tcolorbox}
            \end{column}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \draw[latex-latex,visible on=<1->,brown,thick] (Lab1) to[out=135,in=-90] (lab1);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{columns}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `remember picture` in the options to the `tikzpicture` drawing the diagram, otherwise the node names/positions aren't known outside that `tikzpicture`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % loads tikz which loads xcolor, so tikz and color packages aren't needed
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} %<-added
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{tcolorbox}%\onslide<3>
                    \begin{align*}
                    \onslide<1->{\sin A &= \frac{\tikznode{Lab1}{\text{Side opposite to }\angle A}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}\\} 
                    \onslide<1->{&= \frac{BC}{AC}\\}
                    \onslide<1->{\sin A &= \frac{7}{25}}
                    \end{align*}
                \end{tcolorbox}
            \end{column}
            %
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
                \begin{tcolorbox}%\onslide<2->
                    \begin{center}  
                        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,remember picture] % <-- added remember picture
                        %\tkzInit[xmax=4, ymax=6]
                        %\tkzAxeXY
                        %\tkzGrid
                        %\tkzClip
                        %
                        \tkzDefPoint(0,4){A}
                        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
                        \tkzDefPoint(2,0){C}

                        \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
                        \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
                        \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)

                        \tkzLabelPoints[below](B,C)
                        \tkzLabelPoints[above](A)

                        \tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.4](A,B,C)

                        \tkzLabelSegment[below,pos=.5,alias=lab1](B,C){7 cm}
                        \tkzLabelSegment[sloped](B,A){24 cm}
                        %\tkzLabelSegment[right,pos=.5,red](B,C){25 cm}
                        \tkzLabelSegment[sloped](C,A){25 cm}
                        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](A,C,B)
                        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.6](B,A,C)
                        %\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5,mark=|](C,B,A)
                        \end{tikzpicture}
                    \end{center}
                \end{tcolorbox}
            \end{column}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \draw[latex-latex,visible on=<1->,brown,thick] (Lab1) to[out=45,in=-120,looseness=1.6] (lab1);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{columns}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```