# Is it possible to annotate equations (i.e. arrow signs/curly braces) to define each variable?

Tags: equations, tikz-arrows, tikzmark

I have quite a simple question. I was wondering if it was possible to do something like this in LaTeX:

[image]

But formatted a little more nicely.

It doesn't need to be arrows necessarily. Just some form of annotation marker.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? `tikzmark` library can be of help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain formula using beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254844/explain-formula-using-beamer)

Comment: @STJ While it may be helpful to refer to other related questions, if questions already have a suitable (and even accepted) answer, I don't see any reason why to close them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\[
\tikzmarknode{A}{f}(\tikzmarknode{B}{5}) = \tikzmarknode{C}{25}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,shorten <=1mm,
                    nodes={inner sep=1pt, align=center, font=\footnotesize}]
\draw (A.south) -- ++ (-1,-1) node[below] {The\\ machine};
\draw (B.south) -- ++ (.2,-1) node[below] {When\\ given 5};
\draw (C.south) -- ++ (.8,-1) node[below] {Gives\\ us 25};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{3ex}
\]
\end{document}
```

For the following result you need to compile above MWE (Minimal Working Example) at least twice!

[image]

**Addendum:**
With red arrows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\[
\tikzmarknode{A}{f}(\tikzmarknode{B}{5}) = \tikzmarknode{C}{25}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,shorten <=1mm,
                    nodes={inner sep=1pt, align=center, font=\footnotesize},
                    every path/.style = {draw=red, Stealth-}] % <---
\draw (A.south) -- ++ (-1,-1) node[below] {The\\ machine};
\draw (B.south) -- ++ (.2,-1) node[below] {When\\ given 5};
\draw (C.south) -- ++ (.8,-1) node[below] {Gives\\ us 25};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{3ex}
\]
\end{document}
```