# Annotate math equation with text on arrows around the equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, arrows, annotations

is there any particular way to get something similar to that in tikz with or without any packages?

[image: Arrows around equation in order to annotate]

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing really since I never used tikz for more then using \addplot. But I searched the site for help and found some questions with arrows between textboxes which is not exactly what I need but made me think that there might be a way to get an equation annotated as well.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522441/134144

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain formula using beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254844/explain-formula-using-beamer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a continuation of [Fractal's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522518/194703) the purpose of which is to make the formulae fit in the document without overlapping.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah\dots
\[\int\limits
  _{\tikzmarknode{a}{a}}
  ^{\tikzmarknode{b}{b}}\tikzmarknode{f}{f}(\tikzmarknode{x1}{x})
  \,\tikzmarknode{d}{\mathrm{d}}\tikzmarknode{x2}{x}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,cyan,>=stealth,shorten
 <=0.2ex,nodes={font=\tiny,align=left,inner ysep=1pt},<-]
  \draw ([xshift=-0.3ex]b.west|-x2) -- ++ (-1.5em,0) node[left] (l) {\textbf{Integral}};
  \draw (a.south) -- ++ (0,-1.5em) node[anchor=north west,align=left,xshift=-1.2ex]
    (u) {\textbf{Untergrenze}\\ Untere integrationsgrenze};
  \draw (b.north) -- ++ (0,1.5em) node[anchor=south west,align=left,xshift=-1.2ex]
    (o) {\textbf{Obergrenze}\\ Obere integrationsgrenze};
  \path (x1.north) ++ (0,1.5em) node[anchor=south west,xshift=-1.2ex] (il)
    {\textbf{Integrand}\\ Funktion \"uber die integriert werden soll};
  \draw (x1.north) |- ([xshift=0.3ex]il.south east);
  \path (d.south) ++ (0,-1.5em) node[anchor=north west] (diff)
    {\textbf{Differtential}};
  \draw (d.south) |- ([xshift=0.3ex]diff.south east);
  \draw ([xshift=0.3ex]x2.east) -- ++ (1.5em,0) node[right]  (r)
   {\textbf{Integrationsvariable}\\ Der Integrand wird \"uber $x$ integriert};
  \path let \p1=($(o.north)-(u.south)$),\p2=($(r.east)-(x2.east)$),
   \p3=($(a.west)-(l.west)$),\n1={\x2-\x3} in 
  \pgfextra{\xdef\tmpvspace{\y1}\xdef\tmphspace{\n1}};
\end{tikzpicture}\vcenter{\vspace{\tmpvspace}}
\hspace{\tmphspace} 
\]
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah\dots
\[E=m\,c^2\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you comment out `\hspace{\tmphspace}` you get

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect! I was trying do edit Fractal's answer to add the snaped arrows but could not get the text above the line. That really helps. Thanks again and happy New Year.

Comment: @Schrodingerscat  how to use forest in such a case

Comment: @jsbibra forest is great for trees, and not necessarily ideal for what is asked here.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat agreed-- just wanted to know if there was a way to choose different anchor points on a parent like its done with tikzmarknode

Answer (score 12):

This is a start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\[\tikzmarknode{int}{}\int\limits
  _{\tikzmarknode[inner sep=.2em]{a}{a}}
  ^{\tikzmarknode{b}{b}}\tikzmarknode{f}{f(x)}
  \,\tikzmarknode{d}{\mathrm{d}}\tikzmarknode{x}{x}\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,cyan,>=Stealth]
  \draw[<-] (int) -- ++ (-1,0) node[left] {{\bfseries Integral}};
  \draw[<-] (a) -- ++ (0,-1) node[anchor=168,align=left]
    {{\bfseries Some bold text}\\Some lighter text about something};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Fractal how to use forest in such a case

Comment: See the reply in another answer