# How to overlay Tikz picture over an equation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, arrows

How do I properly overlay a Tikzpicture over a numbered equation? I want to have arrows pointing to different places in the equation to explain their origin.

```
\begin{equation}
    2\left[\frac{2k_{F}}{\left(\frac{2\pi}{Na}\right)}\right]=n(Na)
\end{equation}
```

I have tried doing

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node at (0,0)
        {\[
            2\left[\frac{2k_{F}}{\left(\frac{2\pi}{Na}\right)}\right]=n(Na)
        \]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
```

but the number becomes misaligned with the rest of the equation.

Comment: Welcome! You can use the `tikzmark` library to place the arrows, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522517/194703. There is no need to put the entire equation in a node.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.