# How can I make this radical on beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, radicals

[image: Definition of radicals - Teaching math to young people]

illustration about definition of radicals

Comment: Do you need the labels? or just the formula?

Comment: You can add `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` to your preamble if you want the standard math font.

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522517/194703.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotate math equation with text on arrows around the equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522517/annotate-math-equation-with-text-on-arrows-around-the-equation)

Comment: Is this really `beamer` specfic ?

Comment: No, nothing specfic.

Comment: @AdriánDelgado both. Tks

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I saw but it's very hard to me.

Comment: @BambOo I use \documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor=dvipsnames, handout]{beamer}

Comment: @Leucippus It's so hard to me. Tks

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'm sorry, the link I sent was just to show you how my code was. But that you helped a lot and I was trying to make it perfect. Even so I understand you and as I am a beginner, I am very grateful for your help nonetheless.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'm using the code you sent to try to make the image perfect. Grateful for the help.